# Why switch uses Mac address during implementation of spanning tree protocol (STP)?

Tags: switching, mac-address, layer2, spanning-tree, switchport

We know that layer2 switch doesn't use Mac address ,uses only certain port number to accept the frame.

But I have been read on book as well as internet that uses Mac address to find spanning tree for different purposes like for break the tie.

For example in the below image to find the  `root bridge` lowest Mac address has been used and `Temple switch` has won the lowest Mac address.

[image]

My question is why Mac address has used for switch to find the spanning tree to avoid the switching loop?

Comment: "_We know that layer2 switch doesn't use Mac address ,uses only certain port number to accept the frame._" That is not true. Switches have a MAC address table that relates the MAC address to the interface on which the last frame with the source MAC address was seen. The table is used to forward frames to the specific interface for the destination MAC address.

Comment: @RonMaupin that's I  am asking, switch has Mac address table correspondence to it's interface but switch has  not Mac address and switch not consider as host and it is transparent device on layer2, so switch doesn't need Mac address. But STP switch uses Mac address? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switches that run STP do have MAC addresses because they generate BPDUs. Those frames require a source address.

It may be helpful to understand the difference between control plane and data plane. These are two logical concepts that describe different functions of devices.

When we say a switch transparently forwards frames, we are only talking about the data plane. But when we add other things like STP or LACP, these functions are part of the control plane. There’s also a management plane to describe how you administer the switch.

Comment: Switch's  that run STP,  it's every interface uses one Mac address? Or every interface has its respective Mac address?

Comment: There is no standard. Cisco has a unique address for each interface

Comment: "Cisco has a unique address for each interface  "---- if switch has 3 interface then it uses one Mac address for all?

Comment: No. Three different Mac addresses

Comment: Switch has different Mac table for different interface or only one Mac table that used by different interface?

Comment: One mac table. That has nothing to do with spanning tree.

Answer (score 1):

> We know that layer2 switch doesn't use Mac address ,uses only certain port number to accept the frame.

You seem to be referring to a *simple* layer-2 switch not using a MAC address *itself*. It uses MAC addresses from attached nodes all the time to forward frames. A managed switch requires a MAC address of its own.

> But I have been read on book as well as internet that uses Mac address to find spanning tree for different purposes like for break the tie.

Each STP bridge needs to use a unique bridge identifier, see IEEE 802.1Q *8.13.8 Unique Identification of a Bridge*:

> A unique EUI-48 Universally Administered MAC address, termed the
> Bridge Address, shall be assigned to each Bridge. The Bridge Address
> may be the individual MAC address of a Bridge Port; in which case, use
> of the address of the lowest numbered Bridge Port (Port 1) is
> recommended.

That ID is primarily used to identify which bridge originated a BDPU, so the distributed STP algorithm can work.

The bridge ID is also used to break the tie in case there's more than a single bridge configured with the lowest priority value (=highest root priority). For that, the bridge ID is appended to the priority value and the bridge with the lowest combined value is chosen as root bridge.

You should *always* purposefully select and configure your root bridge. Leaving the position of the root bridge up to chance is asking for trouble. Some edge switch could randomly own the lowest MAC address in your network and root the spanning tree. Not only would any reboot or other offline case topple over the tree but the data flows would also align along that randomly rooted tree - chances are that your core switches don't talk to each other directly but through some lower-tier switch.

Answer (score 1):

> but switch has not Mac address and switch not consider as host and it
> it transparent device, so switch doesn't need Mac address.

Switches *do* have MAC addresses. They have at least one base MAC address, and some vendors will have each interface with its own MAC address based on the base MAC address. The link-only protocols (STP, LLDP, etc.) need a source MAC address, and the have destination multicast MAC addresses that are not forwarded beyond the link on which they are seen.

Remember that ethernet frames require both source and destination MAC addresses in the frame header, so frames for STP need to have those MAC addresses filled in. A switch sending a BPDU for STP will use its MAC address as the source MAC address, and it will use the special destination multicast MAC address for STP as the destination MAC address.

Switches are transparent to the hosts, but they cannot be transparent to each other for the special protocols they use to communicate with each other.

Comment: It should be noted that *simple* switches (just basic L2 forwarding, no management) don't have a MAC address of their own.

Comment: That depends. Some do, as we discovered when people brought in simple four- or five-port switches and connected them, killing the port on the Cisco switch with BPDU guard enabled. The switches get confiscated because they are not approved for use on our network.

Comment: @RonMaupin """The link-only protocols (STP, LLDP, etc.) need a source MAC address, and the have destination multicast MAC addresses that are not forwarded beyond the link on which they are seen. """----- on my question image the link between `switch temple` and `s3` has correspondence interface multicast Mac addresses but these Mac addresses are not forwarded the link between `S2`  and `S3`?

Comment: Correct. The IEEE has defined a multicast MAC address range that standards-compliant switches will not forward frames with destination addresses in that range. Frames with destination MAC addresses in that range are consumed by the switch, and they are not forwarded to other interfaces.

Comment: @RonMaupin could we say one switch interface has more than one Mac addresses, one for forwarding Ethernet frame and another for STP frame( multicast address)?

Comment: No, there is only one MAC address for a switch interface. Frames forwarded for hosts have the host MAC addresses because they are transparently forwarded. Only the switch protocols need a switch MAC address.

Comment: @RonMaupin "That depends. Some do, as we discovered when people brought in simple four- or five-port switches and connected them, killing the port on the Cisco switch with BPDU guard enabled. "----- you are talking about only STP frame not Ethernet frame?

Comment: IEEE 802.1D compliant bridges send BPDUs. Cisco switches have a feature you can enable for access interfaces to errdisable if a BPDU is received. We did discover that (at least one point in time) Windows PCs also default to bridge mode and send BPDUs, and people bringing in personal Windows laptops (unauthorized) would disable switch interfaces because we had BPDU guard enabled.

Comment: @RonMaupin if suppose `Temple switch` wants to send multicast frame to `S2` through `S3` , then when multicast frame come into `S2` from Temple then Layer 2 multicast header stripped and encapsulated new layer2 multicast header which intended to `S2`?

Comment: If you are referring to a link-only multicast as defined by the IEEE, then a switch only sends that to a directly connected switch, not any more distant. Host multicasts are sent to every other interface (absent IGMP snooping) than the one on which it was received, and they are transparently forwarded the same way any host frames are with no changes to the frame. You are now drifting off course, and you need to start a new question or use [chat] the way it was designed.